# inserting values into database dynamically in web page using c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have got to insert employee details in EditProfile page of my project, it should be like the employee who logs in can edit his profile and insert the details and once he inserts, data will get stored in database and next time he/she logs in, their details should get displayed in the home page depending on their respective user id and password.

I have done most of the things, but im not able to get the employee name while inserting the data in edit profile... I mean to say that if one employee logs in and edits his/her profile, data gets saved in the database but not with the respective employee's name.

I have tried a stored procedure to insert the values to employee data but I don't know where to use employee name in that.

Below is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProfile]
    @Full_Name nvarchar(50),
    @Add nvarchar(50),
    @M_Num bigint,
    @Mail_ID nvarchar(50),
    @B_Group nvarchar(50),

    @EmpID bigint OUTPUT

    AS

    Insert Into dbo.EmployeeData
    (
     FullName,
     Address,
     MobileNumber,
     EmailID,
     BloodGroup
    )
    Values 
    (@Full_Name,
     @Add,
     @M_Num,
     @Mail_ID,
     @B_Group
    )
    Select @EmpID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: What's with the sms text language?

Comment: sorry mate only for common words i used it... will edit it nw

Comment: No worries - just bustin' u!  BTW, what's the full schema of the EmployeeData table?

Comment: gt to knw:) well it contains EmpID .. im inserting it through EmpID but i need it through EmpName too... EmployeeData contains full datas o employee like empname,id,add,designation,officemailid,deprtmnt,username,manager

Comment: So this is great for inserting the initial employee values, but your user has got to be able to update them as well.  You'll need have logic that updates the values if the employee already exists in the database table.  That would typically be based on EmpID.  Do you have the EmpID value available to you in your page?

Comment: yeah i gt emp id in d page and employes are already thr in the table too...

Comment: So, instead of calling your `InsertProfile` stored proc, can you instead call an `UpdateProfile` stored proc, passing EmpId as one of the input parameters?

Comment: okie sounds great ... will try it nw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateProfile]

@FullName nvarchar(50),
@Address nvarchar(50),
@MobileNumber bigint,
@EmailID nvarchar(50),
@BloodGroup nvarchar(50),
@EmpName nvarchar(50)

AS


Update dbo.EmployeeData

Set FullName = @FullName,
Address = @Address,
MobileNumber = @MobileNumber,
EmailID = @EmailID,
BloodGroup = @BloodGroup


Where EmpName = @EmpName;
```

Comment: @STLDeveloper thnks mate